# Eclipse CDT indexer different results for C file than C++ file

Tags: c++, c, indexing, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse 2018-12 with latest CDT.  Getting odd indexing problems with the Editor.  Given the below. If the source file has a ".c" extension the indexer complains that type "bool" and "false" cannot be resolved.  If the file has a "*.cpp" extension the type is resolved.

In both cases, the project will build and can be debugged.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using CMake 3.13 to generate Eclipse Project files, although I have tried to manually adjust project settings to no avail.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
void main(void)
{
    bool success = false;
}
```

I have a C Project, but my unit testing is using GTest and are the only .cpp files in the project. All .c files exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Well `bool` is a basic type in C++.  C didn't have a boolean type until C11 and that is `_Bool` with `stdbool.h` having a typedef for `bool`.  So my best guess is it works for C++ files because it's baked into the language.  Does your C project need to be configured for the C11 standard?

Comment: Guess I should add that this is also happening with my own types.  I include "map.h".  Funny that the indexer will recognize map_create() function but doesn't recognize my type "Map" as in Map map = map_create();

Comment: "Funny that the indexer will recognize map_create() function but doesn't recognize my type "Map" as in Map map = map_create();" -- C is different from C++ in that you have to write `struct Map map = map_create();`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar post in an Eclipse forum.  Consensus was this might be a Bug in the indexer/editor code.

However there was a workaround solution.  It you have a Project with both .c and .cpp files in the project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Language Mappings, add a mapping for "C Source File" to the "GNU C++" Language.

Since my build files are being generated by CMake I don't believe this will impact the way Eclipse Builds/Debugs my code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is a bug in Eclipse CDT, which I've [filed in its bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545190).